# Why does peer-discovery work for IPv6 but not IPv4?

Tags: ipv6, nat, bittorrent, ipv4, peer-to-peer

I'm building a [peer-to-peer](https://github.com/Neptune-Crypto/neptune-core/blob/6d28e3925f5519e2d1a90e55a85d1f2434488ef5/src/peer_loop.rs#L317C1-L317C1) protocol where nodes advertise the existence of other nodes by sharing the IP addresses they are connected to. This functionality is called "peer-discovery". One of the nodes I am running has a static IPv4. Let's call this machine "A".

When I connect to A from WiFi-connected machines in my office via IPv4, these office machines do not become well connected, peer-discovery doesn't work. But when I connect via IPv6, peer-discovery works very well. The office machines connect to each other, not just to A. The office machines and A are on different networks.

With IPv6 the self-reported IPs (`ip -6 addr`) on the office computers match those seen by A. When I connect through IPv4 there is no match between the two reported addresses.

Is this because that office machines get NAT'ed IPv4 addresses from the office WiFi router and globally unique IPv6 addresses?

Is this behavior also something that happens on other p2p protocols?

I'm not asking for a fix for IPv4. I am asking about typical NAT behavior for IPv4 vs. IPv6 and whether other p2p application protocols, for example BitTorrent or Bitcoin, also experience this behavior.

Comment: You're the one building the protocol, so I think you need to define what you consider "well-connected" and how your peer-discovery works... What kind of packets are you sending, receiving, expecting to receive, or failing to receive, in which direction?

Comment: You should update your protocol to support nodes that cannot accept incoming connections, which is typically done by adding a relay mechanism and/or a [NAT traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal) technique.

Comment: What IP addresses does your discovery server actually see, though? Does it see the addresses that are directly assigned to the clients, or does it see the same (NAT gateway) address across all clients? Do the clients explicitly report their addresses to the server, or does the server just pick them up based on connections?

Comment: Right, but did you try comparing the actual addresses? (Not the format but the numbers...) Does the received address seen by client A match the 'local' address of client B?

Comment: People block ICMP under IPv4 (under the mistaken impression that it makes things more secure). People also block full-cone nat (only allowing NAT'ed traffic if it comes from the same remote host and port; under the mistaken impression it makes things more secure). IPv6 doesn't need NAT - so that fixes that issue of broken IPv4 NAT implementations, and IPv6 requires that ICMP not be blocked - so that fixes the issue of terrible network people. tl;dr: It fixes the issues because IPv6 fixes the issues of IPv4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> And the peer-discovery functionality that I've built works by simply sharing the IP address of connected nodes along with their announced port for incoming connections.

There are a few issues with this. Assuming the server is outside the NAT while all clients are inside, this means the server will only learn the NAT gateway's address, which won't work either for the server *or* even for any other client, even if that other client is inside. (That is, client B must be connecting to client A's internal address, not to their common NAT gateway address.)

As far as I know, at least some modern peer-discovery protocols (see e.g. WebRTC) have the client explicitly share *all* of its IP addresses with the discovery server – e.g. even if you connected via IPv4, the server (and other peers) also learn your IPv6 address, your *other* IPv4 addresses (internal, external, perhaps internal #2), etc.

IPv6 mostly avoids this issue because there is (usually!) no address translation; however, it is fairly common for IPv6 hosts to have two sets of addresses – a global address *and* a local address – so it is still useful to report both.

More generally, assuming the two peers are on different sides of a NAT (or even worse, both behind separate NATs), the "announced port for incoming connections" will generally not work through a typical NAT, unless the client specifically used either NAT-PMP or UPnP IGD to request an inbound port mapping from its local NAT gateway (and that also only works if there's just one layer of NAT, no lazy "stacked routers" setup and no ISP-level CGNAT). In case port mapping is not available, [you'll need a "NAT traversal" mechanism](https://tailscale.com/blog/how-nat-traversal-works).

> When I connect through IPv4 there is no match between the two reported addresses

Yes, so that implies NAT (at least one layer thereof). Practically all of the time, NAT is "1:Many" NAT where multiple hosts share the same external IP address, in which case new inbound connections from 'outside' to that address will go nowhere without an explicit mapping for some TCP port to some internal address (technically they go to the NAT gateway itself, which will just refuse them), whereas new inbound connections from 'inside' will go nowhere *even with* an explicit mapping (NAT-hairpin is a whole headache on its own).

So if you want connections from 'inside' to work (e.g. two adjacent PCs in the same office), then the clients have to self-report their addresses instead of relying on "what the server sees". I'm nowhere near an expert in this area, but `webrtc ice candidates` might be a place to start research.

Meanwhile, for connections from 'outside', your options are a) have the clients attempt to reserve a port mapping with NAT-PMP and/or UPnP IGD – and, again, self-report not just the reserved port they received from the gateway (which may well be different from the port that the client is listening on) but also the "external" address as well; and b) use NAT traversal mechanisms such as STUN, which often do not work with TCP.